# trying to install compat-wireless-3.6.8-1.tar.gz

Tags: tar

tar -jxvfcompat-wireless-3.6.8-1.tar.gz
bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

please help

Comment: Help with what? The error message is in plain language: You told the system that you think it's a bzip2 file. It's not.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! most files ending in .gz can be extracted with gunzip. If this is not your case, please [edit] your post with the output of `file compat-wireless-3.6.8-1.tar.gz` Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: I am unaware of *any* wireless problem on an up-to-date Ubuntu version that will be fixed by installing this rusty old antique. Please tell us the problem and what the device is and we'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo tar -xvzf file.tar.gz
```